# Postgres usando variáveis no SELECT

Tags: postgresql, select, variáveis

No MySQL podemos fazer:

```
SET @pedido = 123;
```

Depois:

```
SELECT @pedido
```

Temos alguma coisa assim no postgres?

Já olhei na web, mas só achei na construção de functions e procedures

A necessidade é porque as vezes preciso fazer alguns select em varias tabelas na base tendo em comum um numero de pedido, mais ou menos assim:

```
SET @pedido = 1234;
SELECT * FROM TABELA_1 WHERE (pedido = @pedido);
SELECT * FROM TABELA_2 WHERE (pedido = @pedido);
SELECT * FROM TABELA_3 WHERE (pedido = @pedido);
SELECT * FROM TABELA_4 WHERE (pedido = @pedido);
```

Cada select abre um um nova aba no gerenciador DB (isso é um recurso da aplicação)

Comment: No psql você pode utilizar o \set variavel valor e se referenciar ao conteúdo da variável com :variavel.

Comment: Tentei aqui assim \set xpedido = 123; select * from tabela where pedido = :pedido; mas nao deu certo, ele reclama do codigo, não entendi como escrever essa variavel

Comment: Se você fez \set xpedido 123 então utilize SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE pedido = :xpedido; [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html]

Comment: Desculpa usei xpedido em ambas, na hora de digitar aqui errei... mas ele da erro de sintax em \set  acho que a versao do  meu postgres nao aceita esse comando estou usando a 9.6

Comment: Note que não existe este = no \set.